# Does Openstack support dual-stack implementation?

Tags: ipv6, openstack

Currently investigating about this and I still don't understand if Openstack
support dual-stack implementation.

What I have done so far are the following:

1. Created "net1" network
2. Created ipv6-subnet to "net1"
3. Created ipv4-subnet to "net1"
4. Created "router1" and added ipv6-subnet and ipv4-subnet as interface to router.
5. Created VM using "net1" as --nic net-id

**Result:**

VM boots.

1. Only IPv6 link-local is found in eth0
2. IPv6 link-local cannot be pinged

I am so new to this. If you have any ideas, please advise.

**P.S.**

Controller machine info = CentOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which Openstack version are you using?

Juno seems to be quite close to full IPv6 support although they need to fine-tune it.

http://www.thewhir.com/blog/journey-ipv6-openstack

I also found useful this preso:
http://www.socallinuxexpo.org/sites/default/files/presentations/IPv6%20and%20Neutron.pdf